# Что означает строка с typedef?

Tags: c++

Рылся в коде прошлого программиста и нашел вот такую строку с кодом:

```
typedef unsigned short(*GetValAndSts)(INT64 *sid, float *value, unsigned short *sts);
```

Что это означает ? Какой-то составной тип данных ? Что-то вроде структуры ? Я очень плох в C++ и прежде никогда не использовал typedef конструкцию, а в поисковике не знаю как написать правильно, чтобы прочитать подробнее про это.

Comment: GetValAndSts  - указатель на функцию, возвращающую unsigned short и принимающую три аргумента: первый INT64*, второй float*, третий unsigned short*

Comment: @Abyx Это *тип* указателя на функцию.

Comment: @Abyx  большое спасибо!

Comment: @StrangeOwl большое спасибо!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это - объявление [псевдонима] **типа** `GetValAndSts`, который представляет собой указатель на функцию от указанных параметров.

```
// Объявление псевдонима типа
typedef unsigned short(*GetValAndSts)(int *sid, float *value, unsigned short *sts);

// Объявление функции
unsigned short foo(int *sid, float *value, unsigned short *sts)
{
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    // Переменной типа GetValAndSts присваиваем указатель на foo
    GetValAndSts f = foo;
}
```

Вот кратенько что такое `typedef` - [тут](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/05w82thz%28v=vs.120%29.aspx) или [тут](http://www.c-cpp.ru/books/typedef).

Comment: Большое вам спасибо за объяснения )

Comment: Да не за что :)